# how to define a function in an iteration manner in python?

Tags: python, function, functional-programming

I want to define a function which varies with input x in the following way:

`1/x + 1/(x^2) + 1/(x^3) + ... + 1/(x^n)`,

where n is up to users.
A naive code is written for n=2:

```
def extendFunction(f, i):
    return lambda x : float(i) / float(x) + f


def f(x):
    return 1.0 / float(x)


i = 2
f = extendFunction(f, i)
print(f(1.5))
```

but as you may observe, it won't work because the python interpreter does not add a float to function.  Surely I can do it in an imperative manner, but I wonder in general if there is a way to produce a function based on an already given function.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a recursive function like this

```
def IterativeSum(n,x):
  if (n == 1):
    return (1.0/x)
  else:
     return (1.0/x)*(IterativeSum(n-1,x)+1)
print(IterativeSum(2,5)) // random value for x
```

I think this would work. Showing a dry run below.

```
Taking example of IterativeSum(3,x)
(1/x) * (IterativeSum(2,x)+1)
(1/x) * (1/x * (IterativeSum(1,x)+1)+1)
(/x)*(1/x*(1/x+1)+1)
(1/x)*(1/x^2+1/x+1)
1/x^3+1/x^2+1/x
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the input function for n,
and define your geometrical series function as follows:

```
n = int(input("Highest power of term in geometrical series?"))


def calc_geometric_series(x):
    progression = [1 / (x ** i) for i in range(1, n + 1)]
    return sum(progression)


print(calc_geometric_series(5))
```

Example run:

```
Highest power of term in geometrical series?10
0.24999997440000005
```